# Django: Object attribute not saving/updating

Tags: python, django, crud

I have following model:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    #more_code
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(
        Supplier, on_delete=SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name="devices"
    )
```

I need a Patch endpoint to change the supplier from a Device. Everything in the view looks to work, only the device.save() doesn't update the state of the object

This is my view:

```
def patch(self, request, site_pk):
    """
    PATCH the device's supplier info of the site.
    """
    all_device_token = False
    if request.data.get("device") == "ALL":
        all_device_token = True
        arguments = {}
    else:
        device_pk = request.data.get("device")
        arguments = {"id": device_pk}

    devices = Device.objects.filter(site_id=site_pk, **arguments).all()
    if not devices.exists():
        raise PermissionDenied("The device does not belong to the site.")

    if all_device_token:
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        serializer = serializer_class(
            devices, many=True, data=request.data, partial=True,
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        new_supplier = get_object_or_404(Supplier, pk=request.data.get("supplier"))
        for device in devices:
            device.supplier.id = new_supplier.pk
            device.supplier.name = new_supplier.name
            device.save()
    else:
        device = devices.first()

        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        serializer = serializer_class(device, data=request.data, partial=True,)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if "supplier" in self.request.data:
            new_supplier = serializer.validated_data["supplier"]
            device.supplier.id = new_supplier.pk
            device.supplier.name = new_supplier.name
            device.save()

        # serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My serialiser is returning the correct info to.
Do I see something overhead?

Comment: You should not `device.save()`, but `device.supplier.save()`, since that is the object you are updating. That being said, you should *not* change the primary key. Just create a new `Supplier` (with the new content), and let your `device`s refer to that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You here update the `supplier` object with a new primary key, and a new `name`:

```
new_supplier = get_object_or_404(Supplier, pk=request.data.get('supplier'))
for device in devices:
    device.supplier.id = new_supplier.pk
    device.supplier.name = new_supplier.name
    device.save()
```

I however strongly advise *not* to change the primary key of the old supplier (nor duplicate data). If you do that, you should save the `device.supplier.save()`, since you updated that object.

But it is not good practice to do this, since then you change that `Supplier` *object* whereas, you do not want to change the name of the old supplier, you want to link the `device` to a new `Supplier`. You can do that by setting the `supplier_id` foreign key, and save the device:

```
supplier_id = request.data.get('supplier')
for device in devices:
    device.supplier_id = supplier_id
    device.save()
```